# Why should I create tags/branches/trunk for a new repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Using TortoiseSVN for first time. I need some clarifications like why I should create tags and all etc

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating the standard branches,tags and trunk at the top level for every project. always.  Even if you think you're not going to use them.  It costs nothing to do so, and gives you the freedom to branch or tag in the future.

Every tool you use to interact with subversion is going to assume that layout.

Of course you can always insert the trunk folder, and create the branches and tags later... but then you're going to have problems with svndumpfilter should you ever wish to use it to exclude or include those changed paths to split that project out of the repo.